# Enumerating reasons or examples with "for one"

Tags: example

I tried to search for this on the internet, but couldn't find an answer.

Is it possible to start an enumeration of reasons using "for one" followed by what I presume would be "for two", "for three", etc.?

Example:

*I have many reasons not to go in your fishing trip. For one, I don't know how to swim. For two, I don't like fishing. For three, I already have plans for that day.*

Comment: “For one” means “as far as I am concerned”. Nothing to do with enumeration. https://www.collinsdictionary.com/it/dizionario/inglese/for-one You could  say: ) First…,second…,third…, - stating the different reasons why you are not going on a fishing trip.

Comment: I am confident this is not the only definition of "for one". You can use "for one" to introduce examples:

*I have my reasons to dislike your brother. For one (reason), he lacks manners.*

What I want to know is whether you can follow that up with more enumeration.

See: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/for-one

Comment: Please look up the meaning and usage of “For one” in  your favorite dictionary. https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/for-one - https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/for_one

Comment: @user66974 Please read my comment above.

Comment: [Here's a wordreference.com thread](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/this-is-for-one-for-two.3236837/) which doesn't provide strong evidence. Someone suggests "for one..., for two..." is possibly jocular and "for one..., for another..." is more correct, but no real evidence is offered.

Comment: 'For one, ...' can certainly be used as an (emphasised) ordering marker, as can 'First/ly, ...', 'One', 'a,' etc. But the only closely related list I'd say is idiomatic is 'For one thing, ...[statement].' ... 'For a second thing, .../For another ...'.

Comment: For one is fine. But after it, two, three, four. No more for. Also, it is most often spoken and not written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *for one* works, as in this definition:

> As the first of several possible instances. For example, *Everything
> seemed to go wrong; for one, we had a flat tire, and then we lost the
> keys*, or *I find many aspects of your proposal to be inadequate; for
> one thing, you don’t specify where you’ll get the money*.
> <sub>Source: [Dictionary.com — *for
> one*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/for-one)</sub>

But your *for two* and *for three* are unnatural. If you introduce the elliptical noun (*reason* in your case), you will understand how to enumerate here:

> *I have many **reasons** not to go on your fishing trip.*
>
> *For **one [reason]**, I don’t know how to swim.*
>
> *For **another [reason]**, I don’t like fishing.* (or ***a second [reason]***)
>
> *For **a third [reason]**, I already have plans for that day.*

So:

> *I have many reasons not to go on your fishing trip. For one, I don’t know how to swim. For another, I don’t like fishing. For a third, I
> already have plans for that day.*

Here are some similar constructions in the wild:

> *Our Town* stands at the head, and for various reasons. For one, it is beautifully written. For another, it is perfectly acted. For a third,
> it is vitally interesting and profoundly moving.
>  <sub>[*America*
> Volume 59](https://www.google.com/books/edition/America/Bx0QAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22for+one%22+%22for+another%22+%22for+a+third%22&dq=%22for+one%22+%22for+another%22+%22for+a+third%22&printsec=frontcover)
> (1938)</sub>

> There are several possible reasons . . . For one, it
> might be that poor nutrition . . . For another, it
> might be that the relation between the two variables in this
> population is pure coincidence. For a third, it might be that mother’s
> intelligence, which we have not measured, is responsible in large part
> both for the . . .
>  <sub>[*Impact Analysis for
> Program
> Evaluation*](https://books.google.com/books?id=GBxhOT8btfYC&pg=PA127&lpg=PA127&dq=%22For+another,+it+might+be+that+the+relation+between+the+two+variables+in+this+population+is+pure+coincidence.+For+a+third,+it+might+be+that+mother%E2%80%99s+intelligence%22&source=bl&ots=B-LuZRZPUJ&sig=ACfU3U0xtyW2msZj-A21SssRq8BCUnsHZg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiHxte-kvH1AhVfJUQIHf5KDuYQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22For%20another%2C%20it%20might%20be%20that%20the%20relation%20between%20the%20two%20variables%20in%20this%20population%20is%20pure%20coincidence.%20For%20a%20third%2C%20it%20might%20be%20that%20mother%E2%80%99s%20intelligence%22&f=false)
> (1995)</sub>

> For one reason, it was dilapidated; for another, he had got his
> money’s worth out of it, he felt, having bought it for a quarter back
> in 1926 when he had still been a bachelor; while, for a third reason,
> he had for the time being no use . . .
> <sub>[*Killing Time and Other
> Stories*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Killing_Time_and_Other_Stories/FF82lQ7yxr4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22for+one+reason%22+%22for+another%22+%22for+a+third%22&pg=PA108&printsec=frontcover)
> (2007)</sub>

> For one reason, Mr. Winter did not seem quite so angry as he had at
> first; for another, he had not spoken again of policemen; and, for a
> third reason, she was rather anxious to see what the house looked like
> inside.
>  <sub>[*The
> Mean-Wells*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Mean_Wells/nsNTEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22for+one+reason%22+%22for+another%22+%22for+a+third%22&pg=PT91&printsec=frontcover)
> (2021)</sub>

> For one thing, the security clearance process is protracted and most
> candidates are rejected for one reason or another. For another,
> experience teaches us that when they are first apprised of the purpose
> and structure of the . . . For a third,  even when they
> find someone sufficiently open-minded . . .
> <sub>[*The Delirium
> Brief*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Delirium_Brief/kyX6DAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22for+one+reason%22+%22for+another%22+%22for+a+third%22&pg=PA215&printsec=frontcover)
> (2017)</sub>

Comment: I don’t think the use you suggest of “for one, another etc.” implying a reason, is idiomatic.

Comment: It is; I added some examples.

Comment: This use of "for one" is not common in British English where either "one" on its own or "for one <noun>" is usually used. In BE, "for one" comes across as somewhat uneducated.

Comment: @Greybeard: Good to know. Let the OP beware their audience then: AmE vs BE.

Comment: Thanks for your very thorough answer! It's exactly what I wanted to know. I upvoted it, but it seems that democracy doesn't always choose the best outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start start with three discussions of *for one*:

> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/for-one)
>
> You can use *for one* to emphasize that a particular person is definitely reacting or behaving in a particular way, even if other people are not.
> *I, for one, hope you don't get the job.*

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/for-one)
>
> for one:
> used to say that you think your opinion or action is right, even if others do not:
> *The rest of you may disagree, but I, for one, think we should go ahead with the plan*

> [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/for-one)
>
> for one:
> used to give an example of someone or something
> *There were several other people absent that afternoon, weren’t there? Mr Ashton for one*

None of these introduces an enumeration. The closest the usage gets to enumeration in these examples is to imply that there is *at least one*.

I, for one, therefore think it ill-advised to use the phrase to begin an enumerated list.

Comment: I agree. And whilst I am well aware of *for one*, I don't ever remember hearing *for two* or *for three* used as part of an enumerated list. Though I suppose one could say something like: *'Who's going on the outing'? 'Mike and Bert for two'!*

Comment: *Mr Ashton for one* is the same as *For one, Mr Ashton* — both of which match at least the OP's *for one* usage. It's *for two* and *for three* that veer away from the idiomatic.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Agreed. To use *for one* and then follow it with enumeration such as "for two", "for three" etc is indeed ill advised.

Comment: Try the Farlex Dictionary of Idioms.